# Bigger rows with fractions in pseudocode

Tags: algorithms, fractions, pseudocode

I had [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219149/define-function-in-pseudocode) how to write pseudocode in latex. I would like to use fractions in pseudocode, but rows with fractions are a little small. Anybody know how to make rows with fractions a little bigger?

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode,amsmath}

\newcommand{\var}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\assign}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\multilinestate}[1]{%
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright\hangindent=\algorithmicindent\hangafter=1
\strut#1\strut}}

\begin{algorithmic}
\State \multilinestate{$\var{maxWeight} \assign{}$\var{e.weight} where~\var{e} has maximum weight of all elements}
\State \multilinestate{$\var{minWeight} \assign{}$\var{e.weight} where~\var{e} has minimum weight of all elements}
\State $\var{maxDraw} \assign{}$maximum size in visualization
\State $\var{minDraw} \assign{}$minimum size in visualization\\
\Function {CountDrawSize}{\var{elementWeight}}
\If{$\var{maxWeight} = \var{minWeight}$}
\State\Return $\dfrac{(\var{maxWeight} + \var{minWeight})}{2}$
\Else
\State\Return $\var{minDraw} + \dfrac{(\var{elementWeight} - \var{minWeight})(\var{maxDraw} - \var{minDraw})}{(\var{maxWeight} - \var{minWeight})}$
\EndIf
\EndFunction\\
\end{algorithmic}
```

[image]

Comment: By small are you referring to the width or the height of the line?

Comment: @Werner I meant height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase (locally) the `\lineskip` parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,amsmath}

\newcommand{\var}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\assign}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\multilinestate}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright\hangindent=\algorithmicindent\hangafter=1
  \strut#1\strut}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\setlength{\lineskip}{3pt}
\State \multilinestate{$\var{maxWeight} \assign\var{e.weight}$ where~\var{e} has maximum weight of all elements}
\State \multilinestate{$\var{minWeight} \assign\var{e.weight}$ where~\var{e} has minimum weight of all elements}
\State $\var{maxDraw} \assign{}$maximum size in visualization
\State $\var{minDraw} \assign{}$minimum size in visualization\\
\Function {CountDrawSize}{\var{elementWeight}}
\If{$\var{maxWeight} = \var{minWeight}$}
\State\Return $\dfrac{(\var{maxWeight} + \var{minWeight})}{2}$
\Else
\State\Return $\var{minDraw} + \dfrac{(\var{elementWeight} - \var{minWeight})(\var{maxDraw} - \var{minDraw})}{(\var{maxWeight} - \var{minWeight})}$
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]